# Updating Linux Device Driver

Tags: linux-device-driver, ioctl

I'm a LDD newbie and I've been assigned a task of upgrading a driver which worked on a `2.6.35` kernel to work on a current kernel, `3.6.10`.

In order to get the driver to compile, I had to change from `ioctl` to `unlocked_ioctl` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956145/can-someone-help-me-replace-lock-kernel-on-a-block-device-driver).

Yet, the driver fails to execute several of its operations properly.

The driver is supposed to use DMA via the PCI bus to write to a buffer on the host. I suspect the interrupts the device is issuing are not going through.

Are there any obvious changes that I need to make to get this driver to work?

Comment: Issac, could you please provide brief description of driver all about and what operations are not working.

Answer (score 0):

I assume there is change only in the kernel version and not there in your hardware. Do you get any error while compiling?

Comment: This best suits for comment. This is not an answer.